# VBA: why do I get "Shapes (unknown member): Invalid request" when copying table to power point

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

So this error seems to come up for a number of reasons, however none of the other solutions seem to address the issue I'm facing. I have a script running from excel that copies a table over to a powerpoint slide, but I keep getting "Shapes (unknown member): Invalid request".

**What it's *not* caused from:**

- It's not a case of not grabbing focus of power point as I'm able to change text on a slide via the script and select different slides.
- It's not a case of not copying table in time. I set it to wait and I've also put a message box in between and have pasted the table manually with what the vba code had copied.

**The code:** 
Keep in mind I've omitted paths and unrelated segments of code...

```
Dim PPT As PowerPoint.Application
Set PPT = New PowerPoint.Application
PPT.Visible = True
PPT.Presentations.Open Filename:= "#######################"

Set curWS = Worksheets("###############")
curWS.Select
Set pt = curWS.PivotTables(1)
Set ptRg = pt.TableRange1
Set ptRg = Range(curWS.Cells(ptRg.Row - 1, ptRg.Column), _
                 curWS.Cells(ptRg.Row + ptRg.Rows.Count - 1, ptRg.Columns.Count + ptRg.Column - 1))
ptRg.Select
Selection.Copy
DoEvents
PPT.ActivePresentation.Application.ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Activate
PPT.ActivePresentation.Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Select
PPT.ActivePresentation.Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPastePNG, msoFalse
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change your **ppPastePNG** to **ppPasteEnhancedMetafile**.

e.g.
`PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteEnhancedMetafile, msoFalse`

Answer (score 0):

Modify the last lines in your code with the piece of code below (using the ***myShape*** object, will allow you later to modify the picture parameters easily)

```
Dim myShape                             As Object

PPT.ActivePresentation.Application.ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Activate

ptRg.Select
Selection.Copy

Set myShape = PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPastePNG, msoFalse)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it sometimes is not copying correctly, then it goes to the pasting part and it has nothing...

I managed to solve this problem by placing Application.CutCopyMode = False before the selection and copy command

Example:

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Selecting and copying

Range("ExportTable").Copy

' Pasting and giving format

With PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=2)

                .Align msoAlignLefts, msoTrue

                .Align msoAlignCenters, True

                .Align msoAlignMiddles, True

                .IncrementTop (dist_top)

                .Top = 70

                .Left = 15

                .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse

                .Height = 90

                .Width = 690

End With
```